# looking for NOSQL distributed database with notify system

Tags: nosql, replication, database-replication, notify, distributed-database

I am looking for a NOSQL distributed database that has the ability to notify after data changed (as such as call a web service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called *change data capture* or *change streams* in most databases. The idea here is that the database offers a way for you to subscribe (or capture) the changes done to the data using some mechanism.

You can search for `change data capture <database name>` for more details. For example, I was able to find the following links using the appropriate search terms:

- Cassandra: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html
- MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/
- DynamoDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html